# Train NER model to recognize Custom entity

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Currently, I am able to train the NER model to recognize the Custom value for Location,Person,Organization, but How can I train the NER model to recognize other  entities like Skill,Proofs,Vehicle..etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the introduction to Stanford NER: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html

The training is described in: 
https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#a

Basically, you have to create training data with labeled text. The format is a tab-separated file (.tsv file).
Something like this:

```
This  O
is    O
a     O
Mercedes    VEHICLE
.
```

You will need quite an amount of data and probably you will have to annotate it manually. There are tools like dataturks.com, that can help you with that.

Comment: I have tried, but it has been wrongly recognized as City or Person.

Comment: Then probably the size of your training data is too small. Also, try to use more features from `NERFeatureFactory`

Comment: So, I have to train with more training data to recognize new fields like Vehicle,Proof..etc.Then How can I identify the model is ready to recognize new fields?